# Prevent Sliding Window in Python from skipping a range when using islice

Tags: python-2.7

Having an issue with implementing a sliding window of 10 samples shifting by 10 indexes with every slide, using islice.

The text file (input.txt) I have has number values in words on each line "one, two, three..." for easy line index identification.

This is the code I'm using:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for n in range (0,29,10):
        window_string = ''
        x = n
        for line in itertools.islice(text_file, x, x+10):
            window_string = window_string + line
        print str(x) + " to " + str(x+10)
        Stream=window_string.replace('\n', ' ')
        print Stream +'\n'
```

And this is what is being output:

```
0 to 10
zero one two three four five six seven eight nine 

10 to 20
twenty twenty-one twenty-two twenty-three twenty-four twenty-five twenty-six twenty-seven twenty-eight twenty-nine

20 to 30
```

Instead of the expected:

```
0 to 10
zero one two three four five six seven eight nine 

10 to 20
ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen

20 to 30
twenty twenty-one twenty-two twenty-three twenty-four twenty-five twenty-six twenty-seven twenty-eight twenty-nine
```

Kindly let me know what the issue is with the iteration over n.

Answer (score 0):

Never figured out what the problem was with the above.
Decided to instead read the file into a list, then implement a sliding window on the list instead.
Here's the code I ended up using

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('twitter-out2.txt')]
#print lines
for n in range (0,29,10):
        streamer = ' '.join(lines[n:n+10])
        print "from " + str(n) + " to " + str(n+10)
        print streamer
```

And the output was as expected:

```
from 0 to 10
zero one two three four five six seven eight nine
from 10 to 20
ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen
from 20 to 30
twenty twenty-one twenty-two twenty-three twenty-four twenty-five twenty-six twenty-seven twenty-eight twenty-nine
```